# How do I clean Dataset with textual data and use it for classification

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am working on gender classifier on a dataset with many missing values and more of categorical values.How should I convert categorical value to numeric value and which algorithm should I use to get better accuracy?
https://github.com/lakshmipriya04/py-sample/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of categorical variables encoding: create dummy variables and encode via label encoding.

Missing values for dummy variables will be shown as null-vector for each bunch of dummy columns. For label encoding it may be specific class (label).

To solve missing values problem you can impute them via mean (numerical values) or mode (for categorical). Before it could be useful to create additionally missing-values-indication-column that has 1 if the value was missing and 0 otherwise.

With imputation any classifier from ML may be used. Try SVC (because you have binary classification) and start with the simple logistic regression.

Without imputation only XGBoost can help (it allows to have missing values in the dataset).

But you have a slightly other problem. You need to preprocess texts. Please read about NLP.

Comment: Can I drop sub_sub_category,description and title features since it I have to classify gender for given category of product.https://github.com/lakshmipriya04/py-sample

Comment: Sure you can. But it will be not wrong later to return here sub_sub_category, description and titles if you will see that accuracy is not good.

Comment: Take a look on descriptions. Sometimes you can see there 'women', 'men', 'female', 'male' - these tokens can be very useful if 'short model' will be not perfect.